# Android Benchmarking

Tags: android, hardware, benchmarking

I am trying to write an application, that would give the performance of a device in comparison to other devices.  Are there some standard algorithms (for Android) that I can implement for benchmarking performance of RAM, CPU, external/internal Storage, GPU, WiFi Response or something similar?

Comment: There are benchmarks like AnTuTu already which do similar benchmarking. Anyway, kindly start a bounty to get more attention. Good question.

Comment: @RoystonPinto:  Will start soon..... Thanks for Antutu taking a look at it

Comment: @for_Folks_who_are_interested:benchmarkone is an open source app that has implementation of whetstone in java, which can be used with android.  Working on others.....

Comment: Have a look at mine including Whetstone, Dhrystone and Linpack benchmarks (free)- 
http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/android%20benchmarks.htm